# Create a time-based tag for content that will, or is now, dated?

Tags: feature-request, tags, close-reasons

I propose a "time-based" tag, which lets people know that the question (& answer, if any) are subject to near-term exportation or staleness.  The same would be applied to old questions that are dated and no longer very relevant.

*Some questions are timeless.*

Other questions address situations that change, such as

1. demographic practices,
2. uses for tools that may come & go,
3. practices governed by laws that have changed.

Such a tag could also be a compromising ground against closing questions that are otherwise valuable.  (this topic has come up in other SE.s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki/editing features of this system allow us to continually improve these posts, so ideally these posts should never go *out of date.* If the circumstances of a post change, the answers should be updated. And if the question becomes so wrong (or irrelevant) that it no longer serves *any* useful purpose on the system, it should be closed and removed.

Tagging isn't designed to convey this type of information. Tags are there to  tell you **what the question is about**. Tags are **not** supposed to be used to add *other* types of information about the question (like conveying the status or usefulness of the question). In Stack Exchange terms, these are called "meta tags" and are explicitly discouraged.

[**The Death of Meta Tags**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

They blog post affirms that we don't 'tag' questions as "wrong", "no longer relevant", or "not useful."